# Generate The DOM whit PHP

Tags: php, dom

Is there a easy way or what is the best way for generating the DOM with PHP? I have read a little of `PHP DOMDocument` but I don't really understand it.

I would like to generate a simple HTML5 DOM start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>★ Site Title ★</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or you could just use `echo`...

Comment: Are you actually trying to generate a DOM or are you trying to generate an HTML document? Or are you trying to parse that HTML to a DOM?

Comment: @Quentin At the moment I'm just generating the DOM but later in the project much later I will generate a HTML document.

Comment: @remus At the moment I'm just echoing the content but is that a good practice?

Comment: Yes; there are benefits to using the DOMDocument, but if you don't need that kind of power, just use echo.